# how use a method of the page from the masterpage in asp?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to use a method that is in one of my pages from the masterpage ?

I have a method called Clean ( ) on my page Register, but I want to run it from the masterpage , you can instantiate a class page ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to cast the [current page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.page(v=vs.110).aspx) to the type `Register`, if that cast succeeds you're there:

```
var register = this.Page as Register;
if(register != null)
{
    register.Clean();
}
```

However, normally it is nnot od best practice because a master is typically used for multiple pages. So why do you want to hardwire this master to a specific page?

Comment: on page master have a ddl , when entering the selectindexchange the value of a changing Session [ ""] , then changes to all pages and all fields would clean on page found ... sorry for my english (i'm colombian)

Comment: use your solution but does not recognize me page..

Comment: @AlejandroMoralesLópez: so what is the type of the current page in the `SelectedIndexChangedEvent` of the `DropDownList`? Have you used the debugger? Just inspect the `Page` property of the `MasterPage`.

Answer (score -2):

Interacting with the Content Page from the Master Page (C#)
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/master-pages/interacting-with-the-content-page-from-the-master-page-cs

Interacting with the Master Page from the Content Page (C#)
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/master-pages/interacting-with-the-master-page-from-the-content-page-cs

How to: Reference ASP.NET Master Page Content
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0(v=vs.140).aspx

Working with ASP.NET Master Pages Programmatically
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: You should provide descriptions of how to do these things, rather than just links.

Comment: Everything is there!

Comment: No, everything is *not there*. You need to have the content in your answer itself. A link is not sufficient. The URL's for those pages could change. Their site could go down, temporarily or permanently.